# Integrity check failed [mode : settings] while data migration from 1.9.2.4 to 2.1.3 using data-migration-tool

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, database, magento2-migration-tool

Getting error in **mode : settings**.

Added following code to get in which step their is error :

```
if (!$result) {
        $this->logger->info(
            'failed',
            ['step' => $step, 'stage' => $stage, 'mode' => $this->mode]
        );
    }
```

So it showing in which step their is error in following screenshot.

[image: cmd]

Followed all steps before from
 http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html
and 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by replace of following code:

```
<source_prefix>prefix_</source_prefix>
<dest_prefix>prefix_</dest_prefix>
```

By:

```
<source_prefix>prefix_</source_prefix>
<dest_prefix></dest_prefix>
```

Because in my destination db their are no prefixes for tables.